# Dynamically serving django docker containers

Tags: python, django, nginx, proxy, docker

I'm creating a service in which [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) containers are spawned on demand for users to test backend-functionality online.

I would like to make the spawned instances available to users on main domain:

Example: User spawns container `userapp` which exposes port `8000`, it should be accessible on my domain as `mydomain.net/userapp/`

I do not know the amount of instances running, or their names in advance.

I [found a nginx-proxy](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy) container here which dynamically creates configs for [nginx](https://nginx.org/) to serve containers to subdomains:

> $ docker run -e VIRTUAL_HOST=userapp.mydomain.com  ...

I would like to have it accessible on the path. How can I create dynamic proxy paths with nginx or django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out with [django-http-proxy](https://github.com/yvandermeer/django-http-proxy).

I can inherit from `HttpProxy` and create a `DynProxyView`:

**views.py**

```
from httpproxy.views import HttpProxy

class DynProxyView(HttpProxy):
    def get_object(self):
        return Fiddle.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
    rewrite = True
    @property
    def base_url(self):
        url= self.request.scheme+"://localhost:" + str(self.get_object().port)
        print url
        return url
    def get_full_url(self, url):
        result = super(DynProxyView, self).get_full_url(url)
        return result[:-1] # To get rid of a pesky redundant slash
```

**urls.py**

```
...
url(r'^(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/result/(?P<url>.*)$', DynProxyView.as_view(),name='result'),
...
```

**models.py**

```
class Fiddle(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    hash = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)
    port = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

This way I can get the desired effect.