# Mapping django apps to docker containters, addressing with URLs

Tags: python, django, nginx, docker, consul

I have a Django web application that I am looking to migrate to a Docker containers. In it's current form this is a single Django project with four apps: `core`, `classify`, `survey`, and the front-end application `webapp`. A tree view of the project is below.

Should I break this apart and have just one app per Docker container, following the guideline that a container process performs a single complete business function?

If we assume yes, then how should I set up Nginx to point to each app/container using [semantic URLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL)? Example URLs are shown in the tree below.

```
.
├── api
│   ├── static
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── core          <- not addressable
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── utils.py
├── classify      <- https://www.example.com/class?return_type=json
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── survey        <- https://www.example.com/survey
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── webapp        <- https://www.example.com
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── docker-compose.yml
├── docker-entrypoint.sh
├── Dockerfile
├── Dockerfile.prod
├── .dockerignore
├── .gitignore
├── manage.py
├── README.md
└── requirements.txt
```

There are are some nice examples of containerizing Django apps on the web. [One example](http://www.pedaldrivenprogramming.com/2015/10/sane-django-development-with-docker/) shows a simple way of maintaining configuration for both development and production. [Another](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2015/04/19/packaging-django-applications-as-docker-container-images/) gives a thorough explanation of the setup process for a standard monolithic Django project like mine.

With the standard Django project a web server (e.g., Nginx) sends a request through an application server (e.g., uWSGI) to the project. The project's `urls.py` guides the request to the right app based on semantic URLs. If I break the project into distinct Docker containers, however, how might I still address them with the same URLs? Is this something that [Consul Template could do](https://www.airpair.com/scalable-architecture-with-docker-consul-and-nginx)? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321034/dynamically-serving-django-docker-containers) seems close, but doesn't handle linking a whole project.

I currently use Ansible for handling deployments, and am exploring the AWS Container service, too.

Answer (score 2):

You'd be the best judge to determine this according to the complexity of the different apps. Please note that if you choose to break them down, you'll need to have a separate django instance for each one of your backend app.
I'd suggest to break it down into 2 containers, backend and frontend, with nginx being on a third one.

Comment: Good points @Shantanu. I have simplified the project for the sake of the question, but each will also need a connection to a [logging sidecar](https://www.loggly.com/blog/how-to-implement-logging-in-docker-with-a-sidecar-approach/) a common database, and even the ability to spawn celery tasks.